# wildfly-20.0 -Apiman 2.0 Publish Issue

Tags: publish, apiman

when i publish after entering deals for a service
i get only this error:

image before publish:

[image]

image after publish:

[image]

but in console log i get the following warning:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-2) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=Apiman, clientId=apiman-gateway-api, userId=0f238557-35a5-4767-9a75-aa06988f82e9, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, grant_type=password, client_auth_method=client-secret, username=apimanager, authSessionParentId=c5e62247-9862-4a2a-9afa-1c8f8d1beb2c, authSessionTabId=0hURKdKOuj8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems that the default configuration of the gateway is not properly made. I juste made a fresh installation and it happens to me as well.

you can check in the "Gateways" menu, then click on "The Gateway", then you will have some default credentials here.
I've put the admin credentials here, and I'm now able to publish APIs.
It seems to be linked to this issue (https://github.com/apiman/apiman-docker/issues/20)
Good luck!

Comment: actually the default password was wrong ..i just needed to change the password to = "apiman123!"

Comment: Hi, was the default password wrong in the distribution? Or just in your setup? If there's a broader issue, please file your findings in the ticket.

Comment: Hi @MarcSavy, sorry for delay in my answer. It was a transitory issue apparently. I'm using APIMan as a teacher (to demonstrate principles of API Management and OIDC strategies with Keycloak), and upgrade the versions periodically. I confirm that version 2.2.3.Final works flawlessly and doesn't have the mentioned issue. Thanks to you for providing this product.